# Learning React: how to useRef in custom component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tagify

I'm learning React and I don't think I understand the concept of `useRef` properly. Basically, I want to include some tags in `tagify` input field when a user clicks on a `chip` that is rendered outside the input box.

My idea is to do something like this (`App.js`):

```
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Tagify from "./Tagify"

...

class App extends React.Component {

...

   const { error, isLoaded, quote, tags } = this.state; //tags comes from the server

   var tagify = <Tagify tags={tags} />
   const addTagOnChipClick = (tag) => {
       tagify.addTag(tag)
     };

   const chips = tags.map(tag => (
       <span key={tag.name} className="chips">
         <Chip
           label={tag.name}
           variant="outlined"
           onClick={addTagOnChipClick(tag)}
           clickable
         />
       </span>
     ))

...

}
```

The tagify [documentation](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#react) says that

> To gain full access to Tagify's (instance) inner methods, A custom ref can be used: `<Tags tagifyRef={tagifyRef} ... />`

My attempt to gain access to these inner methods was to use `useRef` (`Tagify.js`):

```
import Tags from '@yaireo/tagify/dist/react.tagify'

import '@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css'

export default function Tagify(tags) {
   const tagifyRef = useRef()

   return (
       <Tags
           tagifyRef={tagifyRef}
           placeholder='Filter by tags...'
           whitelist={tags.tags}
       />
    )
}
```

However, `tagifyRef.current` is `undefined`. What I'm doing wrong? There's another way to access the inner methods?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possibly their docs are wrong? Try using `<Tags ref={tagifyRef} …` ?

Comment: @MishaReyzlin I don't think so. with `ref` I got the following error: `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

Answer (score 2):

When are you accessing the ref? Make sure you access the ref only after the component has mounted i.e. in a useEffect:

```
import Tags from '@yaireo/tagify/dist/react.tagify'

import '@yaireo/tagify/dist/tagify.css'

export default function Tagify(tags) {
   const tagifyRef = useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
     console.log(tagifyRef.current)
  }, [])

   return (
       <Tags
           tagifyRef={tagifyRef}
           placeholder='Filter by tags...'
           whitelist={tags.tags}
       />
    )
}
```

Comment: But there's anyway I can access the `ref` from the `tagify` variable (`var tagify = <Tagify tags={tags} />`) in the `App.js` file?